# Optimizing an SQL join on large tables

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, join, bigdata

I am running a collection of sql query's against a large table (7,000,000 new rows/day) on a PostgreSQL database and have been running into some performance issues with first views and now creating tables. Most of the commands I am using are similar to the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE events_tb AS

SELECT *

FROM
(SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
 FROM test_database_1
 WHERE column6 = 'value1'
   AND date_column > '2012-07-01'
   AND date_column < '2012-07-10'
) a

INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM test_database_2) b
        ON (a.column1 = b.column1);
```

Is there a way to improve the above collection of statements to account for the fact that the query is being run against very large tables?

Comment: Please show us the execution plan. Preferrably as `explain analyze` uploaded to http://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: You mention a "collection of statements", but I see one query only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be simpler and faster:

```
CREATE TABLE events_tb AS
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
FROM   test_database_1 t1
WHERE  column6 = 'value1'
AND    date_column > '2012-07-01'
AND    date_column < '2012-07-10'
AND    EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   test_database_2 t2
    WHERE  t2.column1 = t1.column1
    );
```

The way you had it would include `column1` twice in the newly created table, which would result in an error message.

An [`EXISTS` semi-join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) should be faster than a `JOIN` or `IN` expression, because it can stop execution at the first find. This is especially beneficial with duplicates - which you seem to have, judging from the `DISTINCT` in your query.

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about PostgreSQL's optimizer, but you could try replacing the `INNER JOIN` with an `IN (SELECT...)` structure:

```
CREATE TABLE events_tb AS

SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5

FROM test_database_1

WHERE column6 = 'value1'
  AND date_column > '2012-07-01'
  AND date_column < '2012-07-10'
  AND column1 IN ( SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM test_database_2 )
```

Comment: Since you moved it to an `IN` the `distinct` is no longer required. This could improve or worsen the perf depending on the what that data is like.

Comment: `date_column` and `column6` have indexes?

Comment: `IN (SELECT ...)` is not usually faster than a `JOIN` in PostgreSQL.